# Probability multiplication rule

Tags: conditional-probability

Let $A$ and $B$ be events, not necessarily independent.

The way I was taught was $\Pr(A \land B) = \Pr(A)\cdot\Pr(B|A)$. This is to say the probability of $A$ and then $B$ is equal to the probability of $A$ multiplied by the probability of $B$ given $A$ has already occured. This makes intuitive sense to me because it states that $A$ occurs before $B$ therefore we can use $A$ to determine the impact on $B$.

However, I see online that the equation can be switched to  $\Pr(A \land B) = \Pr(B)\cdot\Pr(A|B)$, without switching to $\Pr(B \land A)$. Is it safe to say that $\Pr(A \land B) = \Pr(B \land A)$?

Comment: Yes, it is safe to say. "And" is symmetric.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, because as sets $A \cap B = B \cap A$. (And really, that's what probability functions measure: $P(A)$ is essentially "the proportion of our sample space which $A$ occupies.")

Note that $A \cap B$ is the set of all elements which are in both $A$ and $B$. Semantically, there's no distinction if we were to switch $B$ and $A$ around after all. (You can formally prove this if you desire, see below.) So it makes even more sense that $P(A \cap B) = P(B \cap A)$: they consist of the same elements, so the probabilities should be the same.

---

*Proof $A \cap B = B \cap A$:*

In set theory we say two sets $S,T$ are equal if we have $S \subseteq T$ and $T \subseteq S$. That is, whenever $x \in S$, we show $x \in T$ (and vice versa). We also recall the definition of intersection:

$$S \cap T = \{ x \mid x \in S \text{ and } x \in T \}$$

So, then:

$$\begin{align}
x \in A \cap B &\implies x \in A \text{ and } x \in B \\
&\implies x \in B \text{ and } x \in A \\
&\implies x \in B \cap A \\
&\implies A \cap B \subseteq B \cap A \\
x \in B \cap A &\implies x \in B \text{ and } x \in A \\
&\implies x \in A \text{ and } x \in B \\
&\implies x \in A \cap B \\
&\implies B \cap A \subseteq A \cap B
\end{align}$$

Since we have $A \cap B \subseteq B \cap A$ and $B \cap A \subseteq A \cap B$, then, $A \cap B = B \cap A$.

Comment: Lol what a funny proof 

Comment: Actually I just noticed said proof is wrong ... I might as well write my own instead of being lazy.

Comment: Wait isn't it just $$x\in A\cap B\iff x\in A\land x\in B\iff x\in B\land x\in A\iff x\in B\cap A$$ ? What is wrong there? EDIT: Oh I see, they switched "and" for "or".

Comment: $x \in A \cap B$ means $x$ is in both (i.e. "and", not "or"). A minor technicality but worth fixing nonetheless.

Comment: Yeah I just noticed that too :)

Comment: Thank you so much for this... I searched all day for a concise answer!